# [: -gt: unary operator expected

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a code, which gives `[: -gt: unary operator expected`, when the value is empty.

Can anyone please suggest or correct me where I'm wrong ?

```
if [ -e $POSFile ]; then 
  # Read last Position
  lastPosition=`cat $POSFile`
fi
fileLength=`stat -c %s $LogFile`

if [ $lastPosition -gt $fileLength ]; then
  # Log file rolled
  lastPosition=0
fi

difference=`expr $fileLength - $lastPosition`
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that when reaching this logic:

```
if [ $lastPosition -gt $fileLength ]
```

either `$lastPosition` or `$fileLength` will be empty:

- `$lastPosition` may be empty if `$POSFile` does not exist or cannot be read.
- `$fileLength` may be empty if `$LogFile` does not exist or cannot be read.

Try using quotes like this:

```
if [ "$lastPosition" -gt "$fileLength" ]
```

to force each of those variables to be recognized as a single entity, even if it was empty. Empty variables will be counted as zero in this case (i.e. paired with "greater than" operator).

Note: This proposed solution does not cover the possibility if either variables is recognized as non-number.